# Bootstrapping a pooled regression

Tags: time-series, panel-data

I am trying to bootstrap a panel data and then run a pooled panel regression and finally collect the coefficients for each estimation. Here is the code I have so far:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(rep('1',57),rep('2',57),rep('3',57),rep('4',57),rep('5',57)),YEAR=c(1961:2017), data=Project2)
N=length(Project2) # Counts the number of observations
B=10              # Number of times to recompute the estimate
stor.r2=matrix(c(rep(0,B)), nrow=B, ncol=20) #Storage matrix for the coefficients

for(i in 1:B) {
  newdata.df = df[sample(nrow(df), 10, replace=TRUE), ]
  wols.pop = plm(pop ~ Il+In+Io+Oh+Mis+TDum
                  +lag(cmt.)+lag(pop.)+lag(lv.)+lag(cr.)
                  +lag(cmt..1)+lag(pop..1)+lag(lv..1)+lag(cr..1)+lag(cpiplus)+lag(vlyeg)+0, data=newdata.df, weights=wls.pop/1000, model="pooling")
  stor.r2[i] = summary(wols.pop)$r.squared

}
```

I keep getting the following error message:

Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = orig_rownames[as.numeric(row.names(data))]) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names':

I am not sure how to fix my code.

Comment: It's not a reproducible example yet: tell us what `Project2` is. If it's a `data.frame`, `length(Project2)` tells you how many *columns* not *rows*. I have no idea what the 10 is doing in the `[` for `df`, but that is looking for the 10th column. What line does the error throw from?

Comment: Project2 is a panel data with time-series. Each panel contains information for different variables. You have an idea of what they are by looking at the plm regression. The `df[sample(nrow(df), 10, replace=TRUE), ]`

Comment: as far as I understand is drawing from the panel sample. It takes into account that the data is a panel sample. Unfortunately I am not finding the blog page I saw that suggestion on.  I hope this helps clear things up.

Comment: Oh and the 10 is the number of replications.